# Styling an Angular app at runtime

Tags: css, angular, less, styling

What is the best practice for styling an Angular app at runtime? (p.e. a user specific primary color) The app is running for different companies and every company wants to set their corporate design color in the application settings (free, no predefined color codes).

First thought:
Using less-variables and changing it at runtime. But Angular transpiles them into static css.

Second thought:
Using the style-binding like: `[style.color]=styleService.primaryColor`
But I have to implement it in every component -> big overhead!

Third thought:
Angular and jQuery a no good friends, but is there an equivalent to 
`$('.primary-color').css({color=styleService.primaryColor})`?

Is there a better way? Perhaps an Angular compatible framework, that can manipulate my CSS so I can use simple classes for decoration in HTML and a central service that applies the user specific style values?

Comment: what about directive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like [**this stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jxr8ea?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) : basically, you create a directive that you apply to your elements that will change color, and you store the user color somewhere (local storage, database ...).

This way, you have control on a lot of properties on your HTML elements.

I find it more flexible than using SASS, and you can learn one thing or two about Angular with that.

Comment: Thanks! The approach of directives sounds good to me. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score -1):

I'm using SASS so the thing that I would suggest (if you can use sass) is to use global scss variable files, which you can change in the build process (each build different colors).

```js
// This is the global var .scss file

$primary-color: green;
$secondаry-color: yellow;
$error-color: red;

// This is your component scss
@import `${yourPath}/variables.scss`;

button {
  color: $primary-color
}
```

Comment: The variables must mot be compile-constant for my application area.